# Supplement - Move coupon form after order total section in WooCommerce checkout

Tags: javascript, jquery, woocommerce

I'm trying to supplement the checkout coupon code hook with:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_cart_contents', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form_custom' );
```

so that I can move the coupon code inside the **cart tr table**.

To work this change requires jQuery code and the removal of the original coupon field.

```js
// Hide default woocommerce coupon field
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'hide_checkout_coupon_form', 5 );
function hide_checkout_coupon_form() {
    echo '<style>.woocommerce-form-coupon-toggle {display:none;}</style>';
}

// Add a custom coupon field before checkout payment section
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_cart_contents', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form_custom' );
function woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form_custom() {
    echo '<tr class="checkout-coupon-toggle"><td class="woocommerce-info">' . sprintf(
        '<a href="#" class="show-coupon">' . __("Have a promo code?") . '</a>'
    ) . '</tr></td>';

    echo '<div class="coupon-form" style="margin-bottom:0px;" style="display:none !important;">
        <p class="form-row form-row-first woocommerce-validated">
            <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="input-text" placeholder="' . __("Coupon code") . '" id="coupon_code" value="">
        </p>
        <p class="form-row form-row-last">
            <span class="button" name="apply_coupon" value="' . __("Apply coupon") . '">' . __("Apply coupon") . '</span>
        </p>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>';
}

// jQuery code
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_checkout_jquery_script' );
function custom_checkout_jquery_script() {
    if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        $('.coupon-form').css("display", "none"); // Be sure coupon field is hidden
        
        // Show or Hide coupon field
        $('.checkout-coupon-toggle .show-coupon').on( 'click', function(e){
            $('.coupon-form').toggle(200);
            e.preventDefault();
        })
        
        // Copy the inputed coupon code to WooCommerce hidden default coupon field
        $('.coupon-form input[name="coupon_code"]').on( 'input change', function(){
            $('form.checkout_coupon input[name="coupon_code"]').val($(this).val());
            // console.log($(this).val()); // Uncomment for testing
        });
        
        // On button click, submit WooCommerce hidden default coupon form
        $('.coupon-form span[name="apply_coupon"]').on( 'click', function(){
            $('form.checkout_coupon').submit();
            // console.log('click: submit form'); // Uncomment for testing
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Now coupon block is shown twice above the order review.

[image]

I can't figure out the correct html tag structure. I checked [review-order.php](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-templates-checkout-review-order.html) structure and tried to use different tags than tr td but can't get it to work.